# Checksum function is depended on Unicode?

Tags: sql-server

if its in **unicode** so  the results :  ( notice the **N** )

```
select  CHECKSUM(N'2Volvo Director 20') ---341465450
select  CHECKSUM(N'3Volvo Director 30') ---341453853
select  CHECKSUM(N'4Volvo Director 40') ---341455363
```

but if its regular :

```
select  CHECKSUM('2Volvo Director 20') ---1757834048
select  CHECKSUM('3Volvo Director 30') ---1757834048
select  CHECKSUM('4Volvo Director 40') ---1757834048
```

Can you please **explain** me why in the first situation - it gives me different and in the second it gives me the same ?

there is a lead article about it which says :

*However the CHECKSUM() function evaluates the type as well as compares the two strings and if they are equal, then only the same value is returned.*

Comment: BTW: I get `-341465450`,`-341453853`,`-341455363` for your last 3. They are all different though the last 2 look very similar. So not sure if collation or version plays any role here.

Comment: maybe you have unicode installation of the instance ?

Comment: BTW: I don't know where your quote is from but the **only** part is incorrect. It is extremely well documented that [multiple values can hash to the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)

Comment: http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/18/checksum-functions-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: For `BINARY_CHECKSUM` I get the same results for all of your last 3. In fact for both of them I get exactly the same results as your linked article. Having read that article are you using a binary collation?

Comment: @Martin Smith , you right i just gave my friend this query and he got also different results... where can i see the collation of my instance ? also please convert your comment to answer so i can choose it.

Comment: What does `Select DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_name(),'Collation')` return for you?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS

Comment: I get same results as you for `SELECT CHECKSUM('2Volvo Director 20' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS)` etc. As stated earlier it is perfectly possible for hash collisions to occur. I'm not sure if there is something particular about those strings that makes this predictable under that collation though.

Comment: SELECT CHECKSUM('2Volvo Director 20' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS)
SELECT CHECKSUM('3Volvo Director 30' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS) gives me same results !!!!!

Comment: Not sure why you find that surprising? As I said before I get the same results as you with that.

Comment: its surprising becuase its a different strings which gives same results... while Latin1_General_CI_AI gives different results... and i dont understand why

Comment: But we know this already from the OP don't we?

Comment: @Martin Smith can you please tell me what you mean about OP ? and please forward your answer as an answer so i can choose it ...

Comment: OP means either "Original Poster" (i.e. you) or "Original Post" (i.e. the question). I meant the second one. I was just saying we know this from the question so it is not news worthy of 5 exclamation marks IMO (In my Opinion) :-)

Comment: forward your answer as an answer so i can choose it

Comment: still  , why adding CP1255  gives me same results and when i remove  it  - then it shows me different results as it should ? i stil didnt get an answer the for CP1255 part :)

Comment: That's why I hadn't submitted an answer. I don't know why that collation has that behaviour. I'll update if I find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be collation dependant.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS,
Latin1_General_CI_AS varchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT '2Volvo Director 20','2Volvo Director 20' UNION ALL 
SELECT '3Volvo Director 30','3Volvo Director 30' UNION ALL 
SELECT '4Volvo Director 40','4Volvo Director 40' UNION ALL 
SELECT '5Volvo Director 50','5Volvo Director 50' UNION ALL 
SELECT '6Volvo Director 60','6Volvo Director 60'

SELECT 
       CHECKSUM(SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS) AS SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS,
       CHECKSUM(Latin1_General_CI_AS) AS Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM @T
```

Returns

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_A Latin1_General_CI_AS
------------------------------ --------------------
-1757834048                    -341465450
-1757834048                    -341453853
-1757834048                    -341455363
-1757834048                    -341442609
-1757834048                    -341448488
```

`CHECKSUM` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) as being more collision prone than `HashBytes`. I'm not sure specifically why the `CP` collation has this behaviour for these inputs though.

Comment: @Mid787 - You didn't! I will try and investigate why the `CP` one gives those results.